# Help with permutations for sequential numbers in Keno

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm building a version of the game Keno where numbers that appear sequentially trigger the winnings. That is, the player needs to hit consecutive numbers such as 1-2-3-4 (four consecutive numbers), 19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26 (eight consecutive numbers), etc, to be rewarded. The player doesn't need to chose any number. He only have to start the game. Then the system will pick 20 numbers out of 80, like in a regular Keno game, and the longest sequence of numbers that appears in the 20 chosen numbers, is taken in consideration to calculate the outcome of that particular game.

I know the method to calculate the odds for regular Keno, but I'm stuck on how to tackle this particular escenario. I just can't figure out how to apply or extrapolate such a method to this variation.

I also have to mention that number 80 is linked to number 1 in the game. Meaning: 77-78-79-80-1-2 are part of the same sequence (six consecutive numbers).

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please clarify your question so that it could be given proper answers - what exactly do you wish to calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the probability mass function for the longest consecutive string in a set of $20$ numbers picked (without replacement) out of a universe of $80$ numbers.

For the probability of the longest string being any given $n>10$ this is very straightforward:  Out of the $\binom{80}{20}$ possible sets, there are $80$ allowable starting points for the sequence, and after fixing the $n$ sequential numbers, there are $78-n$ slots for the remaining $20-n$ numbers.  (Not $80-n$ slots because the numbers right before and right after the sequence will give you a longer sequence instead.

So if we let $s$ be the length of the longest consecutve string, for $n>10$ we have

$$P(s=n) = \frac{80\binom{78-n}{20-n}}{\binom{80}{20}}
$$
For example, the probability of getting a string of length exactly $11$ consecutive numbers is $0.00000097$ or about one in a million.

For $6<n\leq 10$ we have to consider the possibility of two strings of length $n$ appearing, so that we don't double count them. To get two strings of length $n$ we can choose the first number in string $A$ arbitrarily, and the first number in string $B$ among $80-n-1-n-1 = 78-2n$ possibilities.  (We have eliminated the $n$ numbers occupying string $A$, the number immediately after, and the $N+1$ numbers just before string $A$, as possible starting points for $B$.  However, this would count each possibility twice ($A$ starting at $10$ and $B$ starting at $30$ is the same as $B$ starting at $10$ and $A$ at $30$).  An additional complication is that if the strings are only one number apart, the room available for the remaining numbers is one larger.  Two of the possibilities we had counted have this property.

So the number of configurations having two stings of length exactly $n$ when $n$ is 7,8,9 or 10 is 
$$
\frac12\cdot80 \left( (76-2n) \binom{76-2n}{20-2n}+2\binom{77-2n}{20-2n}  \right)
$$
and 
$$P(s=n) = \frac{80\binom{78-n}{20-n}}{\binom{80}{20}}-
40 \left( (76-2n) \binom{76-2n}{20-2n}+2\binom{77-2n}{20-2n}  \right)
$$
Frankly, you could ignore the possibility of duplicate strings in this range of $n$, since even for $n=7$ the chance of $2$ length-7 runs is less than one in fifty million.

So for example the probability of a run of $7$ is $0.001315$; about one out of $760$.

For $n=6$ there is also the possibility of three such runs and we will find we have under counted them (by counted each three times, and subtracting three case of two runs.  But the chances of three runs of $6$ each is minuscule, so we can ignore that. The probability of a run of $6$ is just over one in $150$.

For $n=5$ the possibilities of three or four such runs are again minuscule. The probability of a run of $5$ is just under one in $30$.

For $n=5$ the possibilities of three or four such runs are again minuscule. The probability of a run of $5$ is $3.27\%$ or just under one in $30$.

Even for $n=4$, the chances of three runs of length $4$ are small enough that they don't affect the odds much. You will get a run of $4$ consecutive numbers $14.64\%$ of the time, or about one time in $6.83$.

A reasonable payoff list would be (for a one dollar bet):

\$2 if the longest run is 4;

\$5 if the longest run is 5;

\$25 if the longest run is 6;

\$100 if the longest run is 7;

\$500 if the longest run is 8;

\$1000 if the longest run is 9;

and \$5000 if there is a run of ten or longer.

This gives a house edge of about 3%.

Comment: Amazing Job! I was far from having the right numbers for the payoff, which were: sequence 3 (1 credit), 4 (10), 5 (50), 6 (100), 7 (300), 8 (500), 9 (800), 10 (3000), 11 (5000), 12 (8000), 13+ (12000). The post stress testing was working well but I didn't get too far with the testing. Now I'm going to try your numbers instead.